# Android back button should behave as an UP button

Tags: android, android-activity

My app has several activities which can be thought of as separate levels in a hierarchy. You choose an object in activity A, which takes you to activity B, where you can add, modify and delete some level C parameters, etc. If I had traversed A->B->C, saved my changes in C which automatically takes me back to level B, and then pressed the back button, it would take me back to Activity C, because that was the last activity seen. Now, I know what you are going to say. Use android:noHistory="true". Well, I can't use that because some of these activities launch dialogs and when you close a dialog, android takes you back to the last "regular" (that is, noHistory="false") activity. I have tried overriding the onBackPressed, which works until the app exits. I have also tried android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true", and it just doesn't work as the documentation says. My app will start on activities with that setting after restarting.

I would like it if the back button always acted as an up button. It should never take you down a level. Only up.

I am targeting API level 8. It seems that api 11 has some options for clearing the history stack. Is there anything I can do in API 8 to make it work right?

Comment: I just tried the android:launchMode="singleTask" and it works, but it causes a strange delay when launching the app. I guess it is acceptable. :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I had traversed A->B->C, saved my changes in C which automatically takes me back to level B, and then pressed the back button, it would take me back to Activity C, because that was the last activity seen.

Have C call `finish()` after it "automatically takes me back to level B" (presumably by some call to `startActivity()`). Then, pressing BACK from B will return the user to A.

> I would like it if the back button always acted as an up button. It should never take you down a level. Only up.

Then `finish()` any "down" activities when you are done with them, if the user did not do that themselves by exiting them by pressing BACK.